# Django - filter posts by author using a string pk?

Tags: django, filter, author

I'm building a blog and am trying to give the user the possibility to view posts by a single author. So far I've tried different filters to return a view that works. This is the closest I've gotten (I think), but the site comes back empty. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

My **models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = user.name
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("author", args=[str(self.id)])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="user_name",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
```

My **view.py**

```
class PostListAuthor(ListView):
    model = Post, Author
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = 'author_posts'
    template_name="blog/post_author_list.html" 
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author = Author.username, published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by("-published_date")
```

And my **urls.py** has this:

```
path("author/<str:pk>",views.PostListAuthor.as_view(),name="author"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path("author/<int:author_id>/",views.PostListAuthor.as_view(),name="author"),
```

and

```
def get_queryset(self):
    author_id = self.kwargs['author_id']
    return Post.objects.filter(author=int(author_id)).order_by("-published_date")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ashraful Islam. I was getting mixed up with the get_absolute_url and your solution made me see that.

BTW, I got an error when I tried your solution, but I managed to fix my code like this. Works like a charm now.

urls.py

```
path("author/<int:pk>/",views.PostListAuthor.as_view(),name="author"),
```

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
        author_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Post.objects.filter(author = author_id, published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by("-published_date")
```

models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("author", kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```